# Angular 4 ngIf check variable length to insert condition

Tags: javascript, angular, forms

This is the requirement i need to insert to the form but i dunno how to put this by using angular4.

IF Nationality is ‘MY’,
   Old IC : xxxxxxx
   New IC : xxxxxxxxxxxx
IF Not, Length = 9
IF Nationality is ‘MY’ and New IC, Validate with first 6 digit in New IC.

If Age below 19, prompt message and reject the registration.

```js
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Nationality">Nationality</label>
    <select id="Nationality" name="Nationality" [(ngModel)]="Nationality" class="form-control" >
      <option value ="MY">Malaysian</option>
      <option value ="SG">Singaporean</option>
      <option value ="IN">Indonesian</option>
    </select><br>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
      <label>Identity No: </label>
     <input type = "text" name="Identity_No" id="Identity_No" placeholder="Identity No" ngModel #IdentityNo="ngModel" required pattern="[0-9]+"><br>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="IdentityNo.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="IdentityNo.errors?.required">
      Identity No is required
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Birthdate: </label>
    <input type = "date" name="Birthdate" id="Birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" ngModel #Bdate="ngModel" required><br>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="Bdate.touched" class="alert alert-danger">
    <div *ngIf="Bdate.errors?.required">
      Birth Date is required
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: did u tried https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators in angular?

Comment: @NitishkumarSingh not yet cause i not really know how to use it

Comment: @RemyaJ specific on which part

Comment: @Calvin There is a complete example for same on shared link